# optimizing the CTE

Tags: sql

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT a.related_serial_number
        ,a.serial_number
        ,b.role_id
        ,c.role_name
        ,D.Customer_Name
        ,b.cmat_customer_id
        ,b.CMAT_site_id
        ,f.system_status
        ,f.orgnl_sales_order_number
        ,a.creation_date
        ,a.instance_relationship_id
    FROM eim_instance_relationships a
        ,eim.EIM_LATEST_SYS_PARTY_ROLE b
        ,eim.EIM_Roles c
        ,eim.EIM_Party D
        ,EIM.EIM_System f
    WHERE a.Pkey BETWEEN '31'
            AND '45'
        AND a.p_pkey BETWEEN '1'
            AND '2'
        AND A.serial_number = b.system_serial_number
        AND D.cmat_customer_id = b.cmat_customer_id
        AND A.serial_number = f.system_serial_number
        AND b.role_id = c.role_id
        AND related_serial_number = '01c33679-a5b2-11e4-82f6-123478563412'
        AND b.role_id IN ('1', '4', '10', '3', '19')
        AND a.related_component_type = 'CLUSTER'
        AND a.component_type = 'CONTROLLER'
        AND a.related_serial_number IN (
            SELECT related_serial_number
            FROM eim.eim_instance_relationships e
            WHERE e.related_component_type = 'CLUSTER'
                AND e.component_type = 'CONTROLLER'
                AND e.p_pkey BETWEEN '1'
                    AND '2'
                AND e.Pkey BETWEEN '31'
                    AND '45'
            GROUP BY e.related_serial_number
            HAVING count(*) > 1
            )
    ORDER BY 1
        ,2
    )
    ,cte2
AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY role_name
            ,cmat_site_id ORDER BY instance_relationship_id DESC
            ) r
        ,instance_relationship_id
        ,related_serial_number
        ,serial_number
        ,role_id
        ,role_name
        ,Customer_Name
        ,cmat_customer_id
        ,CMAT_site_id
        ,system_status
        ,orgnl_sales_order_number
        ,creation_date
    FROM cte
    WHERE (
            related_serial_number
            ,role_name
            ) IN (
            SELECT related_serial_number
                ,role_name
            FROM (
                SELECT related_serial_number
                    ,role_name
                    ,count(*)
                FROM (
                    SELECT related_serial_number
                        ,serial_number
                        ,role_id
                        ,role_name
                        ,customer_name
                        ,CMAT_Customer_ID
                        ,cmat_site_id
                        ,system_status
                        ,orgnl_sales_order_number
                        ,count(*)
                    FROM cte
                    GROUP BY related_serial_number
                        ,serial_number
                        ,role_id
                        ,role_name
                        ,customer_name
                        ,CMAT_Customer_ID
                        ,cmat_site_id
                        ,system_status
                        ,orgnl_sales_order_number
                    )
                GROUP BY related_serial_number
                    ,role_name
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CMAT_Site_ID) > 1
                )
            )
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE r = 1
ORDER BY related_serial_number
    ,serial_number
```

Comment: I wrote this CTE query and I am getting the result. I would need to know if there is a better way to write this query to optimize the time take to show the result.

Comment: This is just an unformatted code dump. Flagged to close

Comment: Yes, there's probably a way to optimize this mess :)

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) .

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Most suggestion are to improve readability.

Use meaninfulll name for the CTE. Not cte1, cte2

Dont use `a,b,c,d` alias that make it very hard to read. Create a more meaninfull name.

You have subquery without out external reference. You could also make cte from them to make it easy to read.

This one is the only place I think will improve performance.

The `group by` inside another `group by` looks unnecesary. Why include so many fields on the inner group by to then only group by for two fields. And again looks like that should be in his own CTE.

Comment: thanks for the quick response..base on above update. i tried making the changes but did get the result. so if you would have to code similar query. what would that be like. could you plz send the edited code.

Comment: @DheerajJain Sorry, but this isnt a "write the code for me" site. Unless you provide a working sample in SqlFiddle.com I only can just give you suggestions.